# How to find out if a date falls within a certain range? Access 2010

Tags: date, ms-access-2010

So I have a **data entry form** where a user can book a vehicle for a certain period of time: they enter in a *start date* and an *end date*. My problem is that I need to check that none of the days inside of this range clash with EXISTING bookings inside a table '**Bookings**'.

I've tried to find the dates with a query but it just hasn't worked, so any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

By the way, this isn't quite the same as previous questions as they have been about typing in a particular date range e.g. 01/01/2000 and seeing if dates are within the range: I need to do it with values from a form.

**Edit:** here is the table structure of Bookings+ data types

- BookingID- Number
- VanID - number
- CustomerID - number
- Booking date - Date/Time
- Collection date - Date/time
- Return date - Date/Time
- Payment received- Yes/No

So on the form, the user can choose the van they are booking and enter a collection and return date. What I need to achieve is a method to check if the dates that they've booked clash with any previous booked dates in the Bookings table.

Comment: How about describing a bit more in detail your data structure? Table and column names and what you have tried? Are you looking for any free vehicle in a list or a specific one and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be thinking in **date-ranges** instead of seperate dates.

For example, to check if a vehicle is already booked in that period you could use something like this (pseudo code):

```
select or count (or select top) the records
where collection_date_user < return_date_in_db
  and return_date_user > collection_date_in_db
```

You might need to use <= and >= here depending on what you check and how the data is stored (only date, or date-time), and maybe some safety margin for the case vehicles are not returned in time.

To present the user with a list of available vehicles (after entering the date-range) you could do the opposite.

Comment: So if I went along with the idea of using a query and date ranges to flag up all of the clashes, do you know I how would then utilize this? Because I have a process button where if the dates entered clash, an error message must pop up. I was thinking that I could use an Iif statement, but I wasn't quite sure how. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @Kevin Gu - well, you said that you '_tried to find the dates with a query_', so all you would have to do is change that query to check for the ranges instead of single dates. For example, if you let the user first enter the dates, you could provide a list with available cars. If the user enters the car and the dates, you could then validate this with this query to see if they are available.

Comment: The problem is that all of this needs to be automatic- there is a process button at the bottom of the form which is pressed AFTER the user has entered all of their information.

Comment: I tried making a query to search for all of the date clashes, and it works, but I'm not sure how to display the error message.

Comment: @Kevin Gu - is your data entry form a form inside access, or a form on a website?

Comment: A form inside access.

Comment: If you want i can send the database to you